# Correct SQL statement in FME?

Tags: sql, fme-form

I am trying to write SQL statement in WHERE Clause FME in Navigator but it does not work.

WHERE Clause:

```
NAME IN SELECT CONCAT(''$(',SELECT REPLACE ('Roman Ann Jack',' ',','),')'')
```

This sql code suppose to be NAME IN '$(NAME)' but NAME is actually list of names derived from published parameter defined as Multi Choice Value. I think I have to replace EMPTY CHARACTER between names to comma character and that should be recognizable as list for FME SQL?!
I asked this question before, and got answers that this suppose to work in FME2012 or by writing python script.

But at the moment I am curious about this sql statement and if it is syntax and logic ok?!
Can anyone check if whole or just part

```
SELECT CONCAT(''$(',SELECT REPLACE ('Roman Ann Jack',' ',','),')'')
```

is working?

Comment: Is there some reason [this answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14013/how-to-write-a-sql-where-clause-using-multiple-choice-values-in-fme/14020#14020) to your previous question is unusable?

Comment: What do you expect FME to do with this "SQL"?  Perform macro expansions AFTER executing the inner select?

Comment: @blah238 I tried as you said but had so much problems with python scripting that I was tired of trying it anymore (at this moment). Just this. So at this moment I am just trying to figure out what is wrong with SQL statement, why it does not work. I marked what you said and I will try do this after desember because than I am going to attend python training.

Comment: @Raven I expect that SQL will read multiple values from the published parameter NAME and according to this valued read inputed data and proceed them to manipulation in workbench.

Comment: @Z77 Can you provide examples of the WHERE clause you want to provide to FME, and an example of what it should look like after macro expansion?  I think most of us are confused because your example SQL does not contain FME macros (e.g. $NAME) yet still has '$' symbols in funny looking places.  And could you also identify the underlying database so that we know what SQL operators are valid?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could theoretically just use the command:

```
WHERE NAME IN $(NAME)
```

However, the main problem is - as you say - that the multi-choice delimeter is a space character and not a comma. So that won't work as-is.

I don't know about the CONCAT and REPLACE stuff.

What I would do is create a second parameter of the type "Scripted" called (for example) *MySciptedParam*. There are types for Tcl or Python.

Within that parameter definition do a regular expression (if Tcl), something like:

```
regsub -nocase -all " " $(NAME) ","
```

Though my syntax may be a little off, I'm going from memory.

Then in the SQL you can legitimately use:

```
WHERE NAME IN $(MyScriptedParam)
```

If you're determined to fit it all into one SQL statement, then perhaps you could ask on StackOverflow.com, or even http://dba.stackexchange.com? After all, that part isn't a GIS-specific issue, just a SQL one.

Comment: The other problem is the syntax for string literals is different between most DBMS's and that produced by the Multiple Choice parameter (discussed previously in comments of [this answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14013/how-to-write-a-sql-where-clause-using-multiple-choice-values-in-fme/14118#14118)).

Answer (score 0):

I guess that *Clause* word should be removed !

Try :

```
WHERE NAME IN SELECT CONCAT(''$(',SELECT REPLACE ('Roman Ann Jack',' ',','),')'')
```

or :

```
WHERE NAME IN (SELECT CONCAT(''$(',SELECT REPLACE ('Roman Ann Jack',' ',','),')''))
```

Comment: Yes, of course about the Clause. It stays there just by default!
It does not work (both statements you wrote).

Comment: any explicit SQL error message is displayed?

Comment: Just this in FME Log file (blue colored text): Could not find the features in the table 'Person'. One possible reason is that a WHERE clause was specified that references a column/field that does not exist in the table. The error number from ArcObjects is: '-2147220985'. The error message from ArcObjects is: {ArcGIS product not specified.  You must first bind to an ArcGIS version prior to using any ArcGIS components.}

Comment: And have you tried running the same query into arcgis?

Comment: No, i did not try this, I have tried just tu run it under FME sql.

Comment: None of this is valid SQL...